# foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type '' because '' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I Got an Error Like This 
   Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'EventListing.Models.EventInfo' because 'EventListing.Models.EventInfo' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Source Error:

Line 106:                </th>
Line 107:            </tr>
Line 108:            <% foreach (var model in Model)
Line 109:               { %>
Line 110:            <tr>
```

Model

```
public static List<EventInfo> EventList()
        {
            var list = new List<EventInfo>();
            Dbhelper DbHelper = new Dbhelper();
            DbCommand cmd = DbHelper.GetSqlStringCommond("SELECT * FROM WS_EVENTINFO");
            DbDataReader Datareader = DbHelper.ExecuteReader(cmd);
            while (Datareader.Read())
            {
                EventInfo eventinfo = new EventInfo()
                {
                    EVENT_ID = Convert.ToInt32(Datareader[
```

View Page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<EventListing.Models.EventInfo>" %>
 <% foreach (var model in Model)
               { %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%= Html.ActionLink(Model.TITLE,"Detail", new {id = Model.EVENT_ID})%>
```

How can solve this Issue, i'm Using MVC2 Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably what you are trying to do is:

```
 foreach(var model in Model.EventList()) {..}
```

Although it is difficult to be sure.

If you require the syntax you used then Model will have to be an object of a class with a GetEnumerator() method.

Comment: Can you explain briefly, because i am new to this technology

Answer (score 5):

You need to bind a collection as a model. Check this post for details: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

View

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IList<EventListing.Models.EventInfo>>" %>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult List()
{
   return this.View(EventList());
}
```

Or use some another type for model and define property `List<EventInfo> Events` in it. Then iterate in following way:

```
<% foreach (var model in Model.Events)
    { %>
```

Also, Visual Studio can do it for you:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It was question? didn't got it

Comment: Samich, Can you explain it in briefly,

Comment: You need to bind a list of items, so your model should be collection, or your model should be container type whitch have property with collection of your `EventInfo`.

Comment: Also Visual Studio can generate such view for you. Check the screenshot.